# Open a popup window on Magento home page once when user open a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, magento-1.9

I want to open a popup in homepage once every time when a user visits a site.
The problem is now popup appears every time when reload the homepage. I just want to show this popup once.

```
 <?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 if($currentUrl=='http://website.com/')
 {
 ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('subscribe/index/subscriptionsave/'); ?>" id="subscribeForm" method="post">
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dialog" class="window">
    <div id="popupfoot">  <a class="agree" href="#">close</a> </div>
    <div class="popupcontentbox">
        <div class="box_content">
            <h2>Stay in the loop!!</h2>
            <p>Be the first one to know about new arrivals,
fresh offers &  fashion updates.</p>
         <div class="book-column-left">
        <?php /*?> <label class="f">Email Address<span>*</span></label><?php */?>
         <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" placeholder="Email Address *"  name="emailid" id="emailid">
          </div>
           <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" class="btn">
           <div class="offer_text">Get flat 20% Off on your First purchase. Use coupon "INDULGE20".</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
</form>
 <?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var subscribeForm = new VarienForm('subscribeForm', true);
//]]>
    </script>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <?php */?><script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var id = '#dialog'; 
    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    var maskWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        
    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    jQuery('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
     
    //transition effect
    jQuery('#mask').fadeIn(500);    
    jQuery('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
        
    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = jQuery(window).height();
    var winW = jQuery(window).width();
                  
    //Set the popup window to center
    jQuery(id).css('top',  winH/2-jQuery(id).height()/2);
    jQuery(id).css('left', winW/2-jQuery(id).width()/2);
        
    //transition effect
    jQuery(id).fadeIn(2000);    
        
    //if close button is clicked
    jQuery('.window .agree').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    
    jQuery('#mask').hide();
    jQuery('.window').hide();
    });
    
    //if mask is clicked
    jQuery('#mask').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery('.window').hide();
    });
        
         
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
            
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if(scroll > 300){
                jQuery(".gotop").addClass("active");
            }else if(scroll < 300){
                jQuery(".gotop").removeClass("active");
            }
    
            
        });
        
        jQuery('.gotop').click(function(){
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
            return false;
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Save in `cookies` value for example `OPENED = 1`  then during next page open at `php` side check if such cookie present already then do not add your `popup` code or make that check at `javascript` side and do not display `popup`

**JS implementation example**

**1)** add `set` and `get` cookies functions to your js - see manual here about `setCookie` and `getCookie` - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
} 

</script>
```

**2)** simply enclose with `if` contion code which show your popup, as i understood from your messy code it was `jQuery(id).fadeIn(2000);`

```
if( getCookie('popup_opened') == "" ){
     jQuery(id).fadeIn(2000);

     // creates popup_opened cookie and will keep it till browser close
     setCookie('popup_opened', '1', 0)
}
```

**NOTE:** by this solution your visitor at lease once should see that popup on his each used browser as cookies are stored in each browser separatly

Comment: can you please apply to my above code to make it clear thanks

Comment: Now it shows popup once but when i close the site and again open that site ,at that time popup is not coming...........It is coming only when i clear the browser history but i want everytime popup appears when i open site

Comment: simply set `exdays = 0` instead 360 see above example i updated it, (read the article to know more)

Comment: hi, still the issue is not solved..........now whenever i am reloading the home page ,the popup is coming

Comment: Whit what browser you are testing it ? Firefox or Chrome ?

Comment: firefox and chrome both.............I just want to show popup when i close the system then open the system and when i visit website then only popup should come once

Comment: the solution provided above gives you ability to save in cookies some variable like `popup_opened` till session termination moment so same your described close operation, i guess problem is at your side with open popup call or something else you can try to make some debug with `alerts` `console.logs` at different  steps in your code to check what is in cookies stored currently though `getCookie()` before `if( getCookie('popup_opened') == "" ){` condition, also make sure you don't have `popup open action` call at other step in your js which is not enclosed with cookies check condition, etc ...